# Delphi 10.2.2 popup position

Tags: delphi, popup, firemonkey

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Popup1.Position.X := (Self.Width + Popup1.Width) / 2;
  Popup1.Position.Y := (Self.Height + Popup1.Height) / 2;
  Popup1.Popup(False);
end;
```

I'm trying to center the popup on the mobile device. Even after setting the Position in code, the popup still appears wherever the user clicks on the button.

How do I get the popup to appear centered on the screen? Or wherever I want it to appear?

Comment: Did you assign the Popup to the button's `PopupMenu` property? Because that would cause such a thing. If so, then don't assign it there.

Comment: It is [documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Controls.TPopup). Look at *To position a TPopup, use the following properties: PlacementRectangle, PlacementTarget, HorizontalOffset, VerticalOffset, Placement*

Comment: PS - Are you using a `TPopupMenu`, `TPopupBox`, or `TPopup`? I assume `TPopup` based on the naming `Popup1`.

Comment: Did you try to use _Anchor_ for _Left_, _Top_ and _Right_ together? Or maybe you can make your custom popup with `TRectangle` as a container for your popup form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation was confusing to me but it made it clear that setting the TPopup's position would do nothing.

I ended up changing the TPopup's Placement to Center in the designer. Then in the form's FormResize() I added...

```
 Popup1.VerticalOffset := Self.Height / 2;
 Popup1.HorizontalOffset := Self.Width / 2;
```

This works on mobile.